# What should be quickfix/j application archetype in Maven?

Tags: quickfixj

If we are building the Quickfix/j application using maven, then it asks for an archetype so, what should be its archetype?

I tried searching on Stackoverflow but didn't find the answer

Comment: Which command are you using to build?

Comment: i am using the maven install option given in the eclipse IDE, but that comes at the last when I am trying to package it as .jar file. Maven asks for archetype when we are setting up the project. 
Can I skip the archetype OR select maven quickstart